# Downloading the Current EFI for the 2015 MacBook8,1 Model?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, efi

I checked the Mac product download pages and found no new firmware updates for the new 2015 MacBooks. I found many for the MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, iMacs, and even the XServers, but the closest thing I found to ["MacBook" firmware updates](https://support.apple.com/downloads) were for the older models. I looked at the release dates and they are relatively current. I would assume since Apple came out with the MacBook9,1 this year, they would have had EFI firmware download support for this newer model Mac.

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? And why do you think there should be a new version available?

Comment: I assume you are looking for EFI firmware updates for your MacBook. Apparently, there are no updates you can manually download and install. If there were, then such updates would appear at the Apple web site: [About EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Mac computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518)

Comment: @DavidAnderson But then why are the current versions not available? Has there just never been an efi or smc update since the first release for both the 2015 and 2016 macbooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFI updates are available from the command line:

```
softwareupdate -la
```

This is the same information as the App Store app shows. The tools check apple's entire catalog and then calculate locally if any updates are required. You likely are up to date, but this is how to check.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518

Comment: Agreed. As stated in that article "Most firmware updates are automatically installed when you update or upgrade OS X." Not all firmware updaters are available separately anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume there are no updates for the 2015 and 2016 models. If there were, then such updates would appear at the Apple web site: [About EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Mac computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518). I also assume that when an older model Mac is missing from the list, then this model has had no updates. For example, the MacBook6,1 (Late 2009) is missing. One issue with updates is that there is no software way to go backwards. So if you apply an update and wish to return to the original firmware, you would have to replace the logic board. Therefore, there is no reason for Apple to post a download of the original firmware.

For example, say your Mac was shipped with Version A of the firmware stored on the logic board. Assume Version B was installed and everything worked correctly. Now say Version C is released and appears on the Apple web site I referenced. If after applying Version C, you are not satisfied and wish to return to Version B. You would have to replace and logic board and apply the Version B update. **There would be no reason for Apple to have ever posted for download Version A of the firmware.**

Comment: But from what I understand, if there was ever more than one version created then it should be updated or am I wrong?